# (Angular 7) Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode

Tags: angular, three.js, bind

I am trying to render a 3D model with three.js, but when loading it I get the error: "Cannot read property 'scene' of undefined". This error happens because the callback function runs at a different scope. I was able to resolve this error by binding to the current scope. The error no longer happens, but now I get a message on the console (Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.) and the model is not rendered.

I read in another topic that this error can be resolved using enableProdMode(), but it may also have something wrong with my bind. I tried using enableProdMode(), the message is gone but still my model was not rendered.

Debugging, I saw that my callback function (which loads the 3D model) is executed after rendering the scene. I think the problem may be in my bind or why the scene is rendering before the model is loaded.

```js
constructor() {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    this.camera.position.z = 1000;
    var loader = new GLTFLoader();

    loader.load( 'http://.../scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    //Callback function
        this.scene.add( gltf.scene );

    }.bind(this), undefined, function ( error ) {

      console.error( error );

    } );

  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.rendererContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    //Here the scene is rendered
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
}
```

Comment: That's not an error message. It's an information message telling you that, once in production, to get the best performance, you should enable the prod mode. that's done automatically if you use the CLI and build with `--prod`. Your problems have nothing to do with this message, and you shouldn't enable prod mode in development. As the name implies, it's for production.

Comment: My advice: stop using `function()`, and learn how to use arrow functions.

Comment: Like this: loader.load( 'http:/.../scene.gltf',  ( gltf ) => {
     this.scene.add( gltf.scene );
    }

Comment: Yes, like that.